# Print a schedule from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing

I have an array ( 10, 200) with 0 & 1. So we have 10 users and 200-time slots.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Startpoint': [ 100 , 50, 40 , 75 , 52 , 43, 90 , 48, 56 ,20  ], 'endpoint': [ 150, 70, 80, 90, 140, 160 ,170 , 120 , 135, 170  ]})
df

rng = np.arange(200)
out = ((df['Startpoint'].to_numpy()[:, None]  <= rng) & (rng < df['endpoint'].to_numpy()[:, None])).astype(int)
```

I would like to print a schedule like the below:( will print it when we have 1 )
Output

```
User 0 at hour 100
User 0 at hour 101
.
.
User 0 at hour 150
user 1 at hour 50 
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should answer your question.

```
# Enumerate through your output and get the user ID and their schedule
for userID, user in enumerate(out):
    for i in range(len(user)):  # Enumerate through the length of the schedule by index
        if user[i] == 1:
            print(f"User {userID} at hour {i}")
```

This prints

```
User 0 at hour 100
User 0 at hour 101
User 0 at hour 102
User 0 at hour 103
```

Also in you out variable you need

```
(rng <= df['endpoint'].to_numpy()[:, None])).astype(int)
```

Instead of

```
(rng < df['endpoint'].to_numpy()[:, None])
```

So you get the end time as well.

Comment: Hey @AAA, if my answer solved you question then please tick the answer, if it didn't then don't hesitate to reply and I'll see if I can assist you further